# Can this desktop handle three monitors?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

It's a refurbished Dell OptiPlex 7010 with two displayports and one VGA port. It seems to handle two monitors using any combination of ports, but always declares a third monitor inactive.

Drivers have been updated. The monitors are 19-32".

Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000

BaseBoard Manufacturer  Dell Inc.
BaseBoard Product   0YXT71
BaseBoard Version   A02

No USB-C ports (but lots of older USB ports).

If my options are between opening up the machine to replace hardware, and plugging in some sort of adapter/hub, I'd prefer to plug something in.

Comment: https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/support/articles/000025673/graphics.html  ... It should support 3 monitors. Ask the place where you purchased the machine.

Comment: @John Thanks. I think it looks promising, too, but can't figure out why I can't get all three to work at the same time. Unfortunately the desktop came from someone who knows even less about it than I do.

Comment: It may be worth it to call Dell Support and see if they can (and will) help.

Comment: Which resolutions and frequencies are defined for the monitors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up plugging in a USB 3.0 to HDMI-DVI-VGA Video Graphics Card Adapter for Multiple Monitors ([https://www.amazon.com/HDMI-DVI-VGA-Graphics-Multiple-Monitors-Add-Supports/dp/B01I0X4OZ0/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=fly+kan&qid=1640452388&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01I0X4OZ0)), and it worked as soon as I restarted the system.

(I previously tried setting the resolutions and frequencies on each monitor to the lowest available, but the system still wouldn't recognize a third monitor. And I tried downgrading the driver, but didn't get lucky right away -- it's very possible I still chose an incorrect driver and gave up too quickly.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the older driver for the Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000
Looks like the latest driver is having issues with three displays.

- downgrade the Intel HD Graphics 4000 driver to a previous version.
- set the 'Active Display' as '3' in 'Intel Graphics and Media Control' -> 'Multiple Display'.

Credit [Intel Community](https://community.intel.com/t5/Graphics/Can-not-set-up-3-monitors-with-Intel-HD-Graphics-4000/m-p/365806)

Comment: Normally Intel Drivers (I use lots of Intel stuff) are compatible upward. Try the older driver and see,

Answer (score 0):

According to [Dell's website](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000147566/limitations-on-using-three-displays-through-integrated-intel-hd-4000-video-on-optiplex-7010-and-9010), to use three displays, you must connect all DisplayPort displays either directly via DisplayPort, or using active adapters. Using any passive adapters will restrict you to two displays.